# Filling textboxes with strings

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application that has a slew of textboxes that I fill using a bunch of strings. My question is...the code works fine but it seems like a lot of wasteful typing. Can you fill the textboxes from the strings in a loop functions? Matching up the textbox with the approriate string? 
Here is what I have.

```
  var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password) };
        var financials = client.DownloadString("https://api.intrinio.com/data_point?identifier="+conver+"&item=beta,marketcap,52_week_high,52_week_low,adj_close_price,short_interest,analyst_target_price,next_earnings_date,percent_change,yr_percent_change,implied_volatility, dividendyield,listing_exchange,sector,average_daily_volume");
        var jss = client.DownloadString("https://api.intrinio.com/companies?identifier=" + conver + "");
        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jss);
        JObject fin = JObject.Parse(financials);
        string RRSTITLE = (string)rss["legal_name"];
        string beta = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[0].value");
        string marketcap = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[1].value");
        string weekhigh = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[2].value");
        string weeklow = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[3].value");
        string adj_close = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[4].value");
        string short_interest = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[5].value");
        string analyst_target = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[6].value");
        string earnings = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[7].value");
        string percent_change = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[8].value");
        string yr_percent_change = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[9].value");
        string implied = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[10].value");
        string divyield = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[11].value");
        string exchange = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[12].value");
        string sector = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[13].value");
        string volume = (string)fin.SelectToken("data[14].value");
        company_textbox.Text = RRSTITLE;
        beta_box.Text = beta;
        marketCap_box.Text = marketcap;
        wekhighbox.Text = weekhigh;
        weklowbox.Text = weeklow;
        adjclosebox.Text = adj_close;
        shortbox.Text = short_interest;
        targetestbox.Text = analyst_target;
        next_earnings.Text = earnings;
        Close_box.Text = percent_change;
        percentytd.Text = yr_percent_change;
        implivolbox.Text = implied;
        divyieldbox.Text = divyield;
        exchangebox.Text = exchange;
        sectorbox.Text = sector;
        daily_Volume_text.Text = volume;
```

Comment: With window form, the answer is no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jacky said, the straight forward answer is no. But a really hacky way would be to create two Dictionaries. Something like this

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> TextBoxLookup = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
Dictionary<string, string> ValueLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();

TextBoxLookup["beta"] = beta_box;
TextBoxLookup["marketcap"] = marketCap_box;
TextBoxLookup["weekhigh"] = wekhighbox;

ValueLookup["beta"] = beta;
ValueLookup["marketcap"] = marketcap;
ValueLookup["weekhigh"] = weekhigh;

foreach(string key in TextBoxLookup.Keys)
{
   TextBoxLookup[key].Text = ValueLookup[key];
}
```

You'll have to add each textbook and its value to their respective dictionaries with the same key and iterate through the assignment `foreach` block everytime you need to assign.

Does this help?

Comment: Exactly. This is what I was looking for. Something to build upon. Thanks for the help Mohamed.

Comment: If my post answers your question, please mark it as the answer. It helps keep the site more organised.